# Multiple interfaces with same methods name and overriding along a class hierarchy

Tags: c#, uml

The goal of this topic is not to ask how to implement two interfaces with same methods name. I'm asking myself why we cannot make abstract or virtual an explicit implementation of a method.
Here a simple:

[image: Simple class hierarchy]

AbstractClass is an abstract class that implements :

- `IFlexibility1` by declaring `Method()` as abstract.
- `IFlexibility2` by declaring `Method2()` as virtual.

ConcreteClass is-a AbstractClass and implements Method() and `Method2()`. It's fine !

Now, assume that `IFlexibility1` and `IFlexibility` interfaces provide a method with the same signature void `Method()`. If we want to make two distinct implementations, we have to use explicit implementation rule  in AbstractClass:

```
// Two explicit privates methods
void IFlexibility1.Method()
{

}

void IFlexibility2.Method()
{

}
```

Here is my question : Why is it not possible to let subclasses implement these methods as in the first case. In fact we cannot declare a *virtual void IFlexibility1.Method()* or an *abstract void IFlexibility2.Method()* and it's logic because these methods are private. But I think the following syntax could be correct *protected abstract void IFlexibility1.Method()*. What do you think ?

I'm okay this is not the problem of the 21th century. Moreover, we don't often implement two interfaces that match this case. And Java doesn't provide explicit implementation for these reasons.

Comment: Indeed, _protected abstract void IFlexibility1.Method()_ would be useful.

Comment: @Dzienny Define "useful".  An abstract explicit implementation doesn't make any sense.  You're basically saying that any and all derivative classes need to implement said interface(s).

Comment: @Peter Such construct would require from abstract implementors to declare different methods for different interfaces. It makes a lot of sense, as it reduces the risk of programmer's error.

Comment: @Dzienny but only something that "derives" from an interface can explicitly implement those interface members.  If you derive specifically from the interface, you're not "deriving" from the abstract class and are now specifically implementing the interface and thus can't "override" abstract members from an abstract base.  Why not just do: `public class AbstractClass : IFlexibility1 { public abstract void Method(); }`  you haven't explained why that's insufficient...

Comment: @Peter The problem is that if you need a set of classes that have to implement `IFexibility1` and `IFlexibility2` methods you can declare an `abstract class public class AbstractClass : IFlexibility1, IFlexibility2 { public abstract void Method(); }`, but then if the same implementation of the method wouldn't be appropriate for both interfaces then implementator has to remember to add these interfaces each time they create a derived class. It's not the optimal solution.

Comment: @Dzienny wouldn't it be the same thing with an abstract explicit implementation?  The subclass would still need to know which interface it was explicitly implementing like IFlexibility1.Method() or IFlexibility.Method().  it's just moving the problem from one place to another, plus your forcing subclasses to implement two methods where one might be appropriate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Explicit interface implementations are neither private nor public.  They are simply publicly accessible through an instance of the defined interface.  Classes that derive from a class that implements an interface *themselves* do not implement the interface and thus cannot explicitly implement the interface's members and thus deriving classes cannot override that member (for the same reason an explicit implementation can't be declared `abstract`).

A deriving class *could* also implement the interface and thus explicitly implement a member of that interface.  For example:

```
    public class ConcreteClass : IFlexibility1, IFlexibility2
    {
        void IFlexibility1.Method()
        {
            Trace.WriteLine("CC");
        }

        void IFlexibility2.Method()
        {
        }
    }

    public class Impl2 : ConcreteClass, IFlexibility1
    {
        void IFlexibility1.Method()
        {
            Trace.WriteLine("I2");
        }
    }
```

But then `Impl2` is "hiding" `ConcreteClass`'s implmentation.

But, in general; what would it mean to be able to do what you've asked?

Comment: I admit it's a specific case, but it's  a question I had in mind.
Sometimes you need to make a class that has a behaviour. You have to make sure the class implements an interface even if you let implementation to subclasses. And sometimes, you have to make the same with 2 interfaces. When interfaces have different method it's okay.
Explicit implementation is useful but i'm asking if it was possible to do the same as different method name.

Comment: @Sinan You asked "*Why is it not possible to let subclasses implement these methods*" where "*these methods*" are explicit interface implementations.  I've detailed that in that the subclasses *don't* specifically implement the interfaces, the base class does.  A subsclass can't explicitly implement interface members that it doesn't specifically implement.  Maybe you can be more specific in your question?

Comment: "A subsclass can't explicitly implement interface members that it doesn't specifically implement" => Actually, when you implement an interface, you can declare a method as abstract instead of implementing it. So, subclasses can implement it. I agree to that with no virtual or abstract, you cannot do that. Java behaves identically: if you declare your implementing class as abstract and you don't implement method then subclass can implement it. Are you okay with that ?
However, you are right, explicit imp is not private as I said, so my "protected" purpose makes not sense.

Comment: Yes, by "explicitly implement interface members" I mean explicit implementation.  You can't have abstract implicit implementation because only one class can explicitly implement a member.

Comment: if you want a derived class to implement a method from an interface, why not just make the method abstract in the abstract class?  You can't tell the difference between the two identical methods because they are shared between the two interfaces.  If you *want* to implement two different methods then the concrete class *must* implement both interfaces as well as the abstract class.  I don't see how that's any different than what you're asking...

Comment: Assume there is two interfaces I1 and I2 and I make an abstract class that implements these. My class C is abstract because it's a flexibility point in my system but does not be instanciated. I need to implement these interfaces in my system but I don't know the implementation. Now there is an other developper that use my system and make a concrete class. This class could be use in my system as C, I1 or I2. Classic pattern.
If methods don't have the same name it's okay.

Comment: So I make this topic to think about "seeing that C# offers explicit impl, would it be interesting to allow (with a keyword) override these explicit impl".
You know, I can tell people that use my system "If you want to use my system, you have to extends class C and implements interface I1 and I2".
But I have a fix : create two abstract methods in my abstract class. Then, implements explicitly interface in my abstract class by calling corresponding abstract method. => explicit implementation + implementation let to the subclasses. Problem fixed !